# Cannot add new item to project - VS2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Instead of this (captured in VS 2013)
[image: before]

I get this
[image: after]

This is in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Express.
It worked normally just a few days ago and the only change since then on my computer is a Windows update two days ago.
Any idea how I can fix this (preferably without reinstalling)?

Comment: `without reinstalling` - repair?

Comment: What do you mean? Running the installer, I see only Install and Cancel. No Repair option.

Comment: Go to the Programs and Features in Control panel. There should be a repair button.